# From an arbitrary element in a number field find linear combination with respect to basis

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

I have an algebraic number $\alpha$ (a rough numeric approximation) over a number field $\mathbb Q(\theta)$. But I do not know how to express $\alpha$ as a linear combination of $1,\theta,\theta^2,\dots \theta^{n-1}$ (where $n=[\mathbb Q(\theta):\mathbb Q]$). Is there an algorithm how to obtain this linear combination?

Comment: Probably not, because, for example if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ without a precise form of that number, you can find arbitrarily good rational numbers $p$ so that $p$ approximates $\alpha$ alone, without the powers of $\theta$. The key is that an algebraic number satisfies a polynomial in $\theta$, which is the expression you want.

Comment: What if I know the minimal polynomials of both $\alpha$ and $\theta$ over $\mathbb Q$?